# Media query certain on size of html element?

Tags: css

Whether possible to create media query which will apply some styles depending on a width size of some HTML element(div)?

For example: If the width of table grid is less then 800px, apply some styles on that table grid?

```
@media all and (max-width: 800px) {
.nano-table-grid {
    flex: none;
    min-width: 75px;
}
```

}

Comment: Not yet (if without JS). In some future - may be. Try to find another way to do the same. Element usually has some context (surrounding, wrapping) you can rely on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you are using angular 4 you can check this out. I have used it. It's super easy to use.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-if-media

Comment: Nice, that is what I need. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1:**
You can do this with a help of **jquery**. Based on element **width** add a **class** to div and then write your CSS based on the class added

```
var section = $('.mydiv');
var width = section.width();
if (width < 960)
section.addClass('.mywidth');
```

**Method 2:** If you want to globally apply styles use media queries

```
@media  (max-width: 800px) {
.div {
    color:red;
}
}
```

Comment: Ok, thank you. I am using angular 4, then I am gonna found how to do that in angular.

Comment: use `media-query` in css for angular 4 (it be easier then jquery)

Comment: @JamesDelaney Angular supports Jquery. Also javascript will do,